# jQuery Validate can't remove error after dependent field changes value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where a text field's requirement is dependent on the value of a radio field. The validation works fine the first time around when the proper radio option is checked. But, if we change the value of the radio, the error message on the text field stays even though a valid option is checked for the radio. Any ideas, how I can remove the error when it's valid?

Here's my validation code:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            ff_24: "required",
            ff_25: "required",
            ff_26: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return ($('input[name="ff_25"]:checked').val() == 'Yes');
                    }
                }
            },
            ff_28: "required",
            ff_30: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            ff_24: "This field is required",
            ff_25: "This field is required",
            ff_26: "This field is required",
            ff_28: "This field is required",
            ff_30: "This field is required"
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var container = $('<div />');
            container.addClass('tooltip'); // add a class to the wrapper
            if (element.attr('type') === 'radio') {
                error.appendTo(element.parent());
            }
            else if (element.attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
                error.insertAfter(element.next());
            }
            else {                    
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
            error.wrap(container);
            $("<div class='errorImage'></div>").insertAfter(error);
        },
        success: function(element) {
            $(element).addClass("checked");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly sure `depends` is somewhat deprecated, even if the docs don't mention it.
You should change it with:

```
required: function(element) {
    return ($('input[name="ff_25"]:checked').val() == 'Yes');
}
```

Also, you should try adding `onclick: true, onfocusout: true`

> onfocusout: Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur.
>   onclick: Validate checkboxes and radio buttons on click.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options (can't do a direct link unfortunately, click on options and scroll down)

Comment: regardless of whether it's depreciated, your way is more correct :)

Comment: That doesn't help. I still see the error message. FYI, I display a warning image on error and the error message is being displayed in a div with class 'tooltip'. When validated the element class is changed to 'checked' the warning image disappears. But in this case, the error image still stays after 'No' has been checked for ff_25. As I said, it works fine the first time but acts funky when I switch the ff_25 values.

Comment: @peace4theapes, you've edited your question with the code from Razor's answer, which then renders Razor's answer meaningless.  I'm going to roll back your edit.  Please simply _append_ your question with any new information.